# html video is not supporting on mobile

Tags: html, video

In the below code the video is working on ie, chrome and mozilla

But the video is not supporting on mobile

What is the solution friends help me:

```
<video width="400" height="360" autoplay loop>
  <source src="http://www.example.co.in/videos/trytek.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.example.co.in/videos/trytek.ogg" type="video/ogg"> 
</video>
```

Comment: look forward to http://www.expertisemobile.com/2011/10/28/html5-video-and-audio-tags-support-on-mobile-device-real-world-feedback/

Answer (score 0):

Which mobile OS (and version), and which mobile browser (and version) are you using?
1) Not all video types are supported by all mobile browsers:
[HTML5 Video Element Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/video)

2) You may require special handling to run the video:
[Android < 2.3 HTML5 Video handling](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/)

Let me know how it goes.